# Google App Engine HTTPS listening ports 8443 or 3443

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am testing an application in the App Engine Flexible Environment, and at some point I will need to process some WebHooks sent on TCP ports 8443 or 3443.

As long as I could test, App Engine load balancer (which deals with HTTPS connections) only accepts connections on port 443. Is there a way to listen HTTPS connection on these other ports? I couldn't find App Engine specific firewall configuration at this level (load balancer).

EDIT:

After some real testing, I found out that the WebHooks are working properly. The errors I was facing were probably related to the way that tests were done.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to listen on different ports rather than 443 by using a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build), however there's a caveat as you won't be able to point through the appspot.com domain but instead you have to point to the IP directly.

The process to do this is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#port_forwarding):

> 1. For example, if you want to forward TCP traffic from port 2222. In the network settings of your app.yaml, include:

```
network:
  forwarded_ports:
    - 2222/tcp
```

> 2. Specify a firewall rule in the Cloud Console or using gcloud compute firewall-rules create to allow traffic from any source (0.0.0.0/0) and from tcp:2222.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create "tcp-rule" --allow=tcp:2222
  --source-ranges="0.0.0.0/0" --description="Listening on 2222"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I was not looking to forward ports from the application to the load balancer. Those additional ports should be handled directly by the load balancer, since the HTTPS connection is terminated at that level and forwarded as simple HTTP to the app.

Comment: @Antonio Guglielmi, can you confirm if your issue stands resolved or if you are still facing any issue ?